# BDD Result: What to do if I expect an error

Tags: nunit, bdd, specflow

I'm trying a little bit the BDD approach and I've a question:

I've made a scenario for a fictive bank account:

```
Scenario: No money as new customer
    Given I'm a customer
    And I've not any deposit
    When I try to withdraw 50 dollars
    Then I should get an error
```

I'm implementing it with Specflow + NUnit.

I'm a little bit borried by the `Then I should get an error`.
Because currently I've a `bool TryWithdraw(double amount)`.

I can see two way of making it working:

1. Change the BDD requirement to remove the THEN
2. Store the result of the WHEN, and check it in the THEN

What would be the correct approach? Is my BDD requirement correct or do I have to store the result?

Comment: second solution seems appropriate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BDD Tests are like unit tests structured. You have an arrange part, an act part and at the end the assert part:

- Given = arrange
- When = act
- Then = assert

So storing the result of your act (*When I try to withdraw 50 dollars*) is complete valid.
Then you do your assert based on the result.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't quite sure, and I didn't found a lot of resources for specflow

Comment: For such general BDD question, you could also look at Cucumber, as SpecFlow is the Cucumber implementation for .NET.

Comment: Yeah for not, apart that specflow target .Net, it's not quite clear what are the differences.